# Как лексический анализатор кода работает со "значащими" пробелами? С++

Tags: c++, компиляция, лексический-анализатор, лексер

Решил начать изучать, хотя бы в общих чертах, как работают анализаторы. Начал с лексера. В некоторых статьях сказано, что лексер при сканировании кода сначала убирает все пробелы из файла. Отсюда вопрос, а что лексер делает со "значащими" пробелами? Например:

```
// Тут если убрать пробелы, то будет
// Просто неинициализированное имя:
// typedefintINT
typedef int INT
```

Или:

```
// Без пробелов будет inta и лексер не сможет выделить токен правильно
int a = 10;
```

Как это решается в лексических анализаторах?

Comment: Наверное из этих статей пропало слово *лишние*

Comment: @avp, а смысл убирать лишние пробелы? Парсер плюсов работает потоково и добавлять предобработку файла в виде убирания лишних пробелов мне кажется чем-то нерациональным.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, понятно же, он это делает по ходу дела, в ходе поиcка начала лексемы. Что-то типа `get_lexem() { skip_delimiters(); ... return lex;}` (в реальном компиляторе такой код будет генериться автоматически каким-нибудь lex-ом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я делал парсинг, то разбирал код по токенам, а не по символам. Массив из 3 токенов - это одно, а массив из одного токена - совершенно другое. Пробелы имеют значение для разделения токенов, но сами значимым токеном не являются. Скорее всего имеется в виду именно это.

Впрочем, у Си++ вполне есть строгая грамматика и она вполне может работать посимвольно - не уверен. В таком случае пробелы трогать нельзя.

Comment: И все же я не понял, что лексер делает с пробелами? Ведь, как вы сказали, в некоторых местах пробелы служат разделителем токенов, их ведь нельзя убирать в любом случае, как я понимаю?

Comment: @ComeInRage, я регуляркой вытаскивал массив токенов сразу. Всё что не попало под регулярку - незначащий мусор. С натяжкой это можно назвать убиранием поскольку программа с этим не работает и в массив токенов оно не попадает.